# Email variable order.getShippingAddress().getStreet1() returns null

Tags: magento2, email-templates, shipping-address, variables

I have created custom order email template and placed some order shipping address variables inside it.
Most variables work ok, but the following are always returning no value:

```
{{var order.getShippingAddress().getStreet1()}}
{{var order.getShippingAddress().getCountry()}}
{{var order.getShippingAddress().getCountryModel().getName()}}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead :

```
{{var order.getShippingAddress().getStreetLine(1)}}
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution. Do you know about the country field too?

Comment: Do you mean to say that you tried this and it's not working `{{var order.getShippingAddress().getCountry()}}`

Comment: please try this - `{{var order.getShippingAddress().getCountryId()}}` for getting the country code.

Answer (score 1):

Please try with below way to check street deatils :

```
 {{var $order.getShippingAddress().getStreetLine(1) }}
 {{var $order.getShippingAddress().getStreetLine(2) }}
```

for more data if you want than check with below url.

https://hotexamples.com/examples/magento.sales.model.order/Address/getStreetLine/php-address-getstreetline-method-examples.html